# save file to client's desktop from server desktop

Tags: c#, asp.net, dbf

my default iis website is configured on a different pc (server) and  im calling the website thru a laptop (client). Is it possible, *[programmatically]* a created directory or file from a server side, can be saved into client side?

here's a sample function I modified, it is attached on a control page - Onclick event:

```
  string FilePath = "C:\\interface\\";  <-- SERVER PC

  string DBF_FileName = "CTRAN.DBF"; 

  OleDbConnection conn = new 
  OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;");

  OleDbCommand CmdSql = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO CTRAN.DBF (CHR_CCOMP, 
  CHR_CDEPT) VALUES (@CHR_CCOMP, @CHR_CDEPT)", conn);

            conn.Open();
            CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHR_CCOMP", 1);
            CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHR_CDEPT", 2);
            CmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

   //SAVE to CLIENT'S DESKTOP

   System.IO.File.Copy(C:\\interface\\CTRAN.DBF, "Client's Directory", true);
```

apparently, it only save's on the server pc not on the client's pc. :(

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem. If it is what I think it is, this is my question: what if one website on the web did something like this: `System.IO.File.Delete(@"Client://C:\Program Files")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible to write file from server to client in web application.

You can provide link to download file and let user save it. I.e. using ASP.Net MVC return [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) result with whatever stream you want.

Comment: I see, thank you sir @Alexei and for the link as well.